# Cache all database queries in rails 2.3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

How can I cache all of my queries.

first request:

```
@user = User.all
```

second request

```
@user = User.all # Cached
```

Are there any useful plugins to do this?

I'm on production mode. I can't seem to see any cached phrase to confirm that my rails app is caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your config/environments/production.rb

> ```
> config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
> ```

caching is disabled by default for development and test, and enabled for production.

Query caching is a Rails feature that caches the result set returned by each query so that if Rails encounters the same query again for that request, it will use the cached result set as opposed to running the query against the database again.

For example:

> ```
>  class UsersController < ActionController
>
>  def index
>    # Run a find query
>    @users = User.all
>
>    ...
>
>    # Run the same query again
>   @users = User.all
>
>    end
>
>  end
> ```

The second time the same query is run against the database, it’s not actually going to hit the database. The first time the result is returned from the query it is stored in the query cache (in memory) and the second time it’s pulled from memory.

Check it at your console

> User Load (?ms)  SELECT `User`.* FROM `User`
>
> Completed 200 OK in ?ms (Views: ?ms | ActiveRecord: ?ms)

You can compare it with first time load and second time load.

You can use Dalli gem from https://github.com/mperham/dalli for store your cache to memcached server.